# Getting following error in console while solr connection to Mongo . No error in solr log

Tags: mongodb, solr

Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()Lcom/mongodb/ReadPreference;
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoDataSource.init(MongoDataSource.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:397)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:100)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.MongoEntityProcessor.init(MongoEntityProcessor.java:33)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:77)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:434)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:415)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:330)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:233)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:466)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Missing methods are usually caused by using the wrong version of the library. Which version are you currently using, and are you sure that the correct version is being loaded within your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

There are jar files interdependent (though I took all latest was not compatible). Finally the combination worked is listed below.
solr-dataimporthandler-8.3.0.jar
solr-mongo-importer-1.0.0.jar
mongo-java-driver-2.13.2.jar

It was frustrating.